# help with upload function

Tags: uploading

I have been asked to review an upload function.

The user can upload multiple files to a folder called a 'binder' using an uploader. This is called Add to Binder function.

A binder is just a shorthand way of saying it is a kind of folder that contains shortcuts to other documents in the system; the user adds to the binder by locating to these files. To be be clear: these files are not copied and moved across, just a metadata instance of them is inserted into the binder.

But the business requires that the user can add to the binder by uploading from their hard drive too. And this causes problems because the user cannot upload directly into the binder; s/he has to locate to the folder structure, upload there, then link that uploaded file to the binder. Here's a diagram:

[image]

This is a horrible workflow and one I must streamline

**my question**: is there a way of making this workflow fluid? one possible wireframe might be:

[image]

(left hand side is directory on system, right hand side is files to be added into the binder and attach file should really say add to binder for consistency)

The secondary function 'attach from local drive' launches another window where the user picks a local file then follows the workflow as in the first diagram (see? its getting MESSY)

OR: do I remove the attach from local drive function as the user should only be uploading into the directory structure during the times they are in folders, not binders.

EDIT

me and a colleague came up with a possible solution on click attach from local drive:
[image]

so on click the file will be autofiled in some default directory (by the system looking for a root directory folder the user has, for example but the user has an option to change
if they need to) and at the same time the uploaded file will be added to the attach file to binder list shown in the first two wires.

Comment: Does a user have more than one binder? In other words, does it provide a way for a user to create arbitrary collections files or is it just a way for them to create a single list of their favourite files? Just trying to picture the scene.

Comment: Multiple binders

Comment: A couple questions: 1) Does the user primarily interact with binders or the system directory when using the rest of this application? 2) Is the system directory shared by all users or does each have their own directory? Please give an example of what the user would use the binder for and the system directory for, besides uploading.

Comment: Hi Benortiz
The user interacts more with folders than binders. System directory is shared with all users. A binder is a shortcut for a collection of files across the directory, it saves the user from trawling across the entire system for commonly accessed files.

Answer (score 1):

Let me answer, but I am not sure understood your question and find out what you want correctly, But maybe this can help you.

Google drive let users to upload file and multiple file too, This is the way that Google is using:
[image]

There are check box beside each file that uploaded and let user to select each file what they need and delete, rename or move it.

**What about multiple file upload?**

OK, I think I should show you another example from Google Drive and Microsoft OneDrive file upload:

Google Drive
[image]

OneDrive:
[image]

***note**:Sorry if this is not good answer, But seeing demos are good idea to making a better User Experience*

Comment: @colmcq your welcome and sorry if didn't help you!